# DB2 date format day leading zero

Tags: sql, db2

How can I remove leading zero from a day in my query?

It returns e.g. "Mar 02" when I use this:

```
select VARCHAR_FORMAT(myDateField, 'Mon DD') FROM mytable
```

I need just "Mar 2"

Comment: Did you try 'Mon D'?

Comment: D returns just day of week

Comment: ...generally speaking, it's better to do formatting at the presentation layer, not the db layer (especially because it's rare for the db to know what localization to use for international stuff).  Most application languages have better ways to do date formatting anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a particular format for days without leading zeros.  So, one option is:

```
select REPLACE(VARCHAR_FORMAT(myDateField, 'Mon DD'), ' 0', ' ')
```

Comment: REPLACE will replace 0 in 10, 20... I'm looking for some standard solution/format... But if there is no simple solution I will play with REPLACE

Comment: @VladP . . . It would if there were no space in the pattern before the zero.  But it won't with this expression.

Comment: ah.. yeah.. you are right.. my bad.. long day.. Thank you  Mr. Linoff